# HTML Dropdown Will Not Position Correctly

Tags: html, css, navigation, dropdown

I have made a dropdown menu to be used for three different links across my websites nagivation bar. The dropdown itself is working fine however the problem I am having is I cannot get the dropdown to position itself in the middle of each of the navigation links, it is positioned correctly for one of the links however the other are not as they are different character lengths. The dropdown is done entirely in HTML and CSS, the rest of the website is also using Django however it is not used in the dropdown.

Picture of Problem -

(This is one of the links where the dropdown is not positioned correctly, you can see the triangle at the top of the box is not lined up with the middle of the link.)

[image: This is one of the links where the dropdown is not positioned correctly]

(In this one you can see the triangle is more or less centered with the link however I believe this is just by chance)

[image: This is one of the links where the dropdown is correctly positioned]

Dropdown HTML (For one of the dropdowns however it is identical to the others)

```
      <li class="link-drop"><a href="">Employer</a>
          <ul class="link-drop-ul">
              <div class="triangle"></div>
              <div class="link-drop-box">
                  <li><a class="link-drop-a" href="{% url 'createjoblisting' %}">Add Listing</a></li>
                  <li><a class="link-drop-a" href="{% url 'featurenotimplemented' %}">How it works</a></li>
              </div>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

Dropdown CSS (This is the same across all)

```
.link-drop {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.link-drop li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.link-drop a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ebebee;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.link-drop-ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.link-drop-box {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px -10px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 122px;
    margin: auto;
}
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid white;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.link-drop-ul li {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.link-drop-ul li a {
    color: black;
    float: none;
}
.link-drop-ul li a:hover {
    color: #d1d1d1;
}
.link-drop:hover > .link-drop-ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 55px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it is not hosted yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of the problem you are facing. I've changed/moved/added some CSS.

```css
.link-drop {
    position:relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.link-drop li {
    list-style-type: none;

}
.link-drop a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ebebee;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.link-drop-ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 122px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translatex(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translatex(-50%);
    -o-transform: translatex(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-50%);
    transform: translatex(-50%);
    top:100%;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.link-drop-box {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px -10px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid white;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.link-drop-ul li {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.link-drop-ul li a {
    color: black;
    float: none;
}
.link-drop-ul li a:hover {
    color: #d1d1d1;
}
.link-drop:hover > .link-drop-ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

}
```

```html
<li class="link-drop"><a href="">Employer</a>
          <ul class="link-drop-ul">
              <div class="triangle"></div>
              <div class="link-drop-box">
                  <li><a class="link-drop-a" href="{% url 'createjoblisting' %}">Add Listing</a></li>
                  <li><a class="link-drop-a" href="{% url 'featurenotimplemented' %}">How it works</a></li>
              </div>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried your solution and while it did center the code to the navigation link it is forced the drop-down up so it overlaps with the navigation bar. Also it will not stay open when I hover over it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle or post your complete code of the menu. Otherwise, it will take hours to give you a complete solution and won't be able to spend that much time. I guess you understand it.  :)

Comment: I have modified it a little bit and got it to be positioned where it use to be however it will not stay open if I try to hover over it.

Comment: Perfect, the solved the issue! I appreciate the help :)